# Scripting *restricted* UI to Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Consider requirements for a guest list app (for a club):

1. Guest list as a Google spreadsheet with two columns:

   ```
   name: name of guest
   entered: yes, iff guest has entered
   ```
2. Web app for people at the door allows searching for a guest by name, and marking her or him as entered.
3. People at the door are *not* allowed to change the guest list, other than marking guests as entered or not (obviously). They should have a password that gives them access only to the app (*point 2*), but not to the spreadsheet (*point 1*).

I wonder: *Is it possible to write the user interface in Google Docs Script? If so, how do I do authentication with regards to point 3?*

Otherwise, of course, I could just write the UI, say in PHP, and have it authenticate against the Google account using OAuth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night's sleep, I just had a look at the [deployment options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps#deploying). What I want should be possible by setting permissions as follows:

- *Execute as:* `admin@example.com`
- *Allow access to:* any member of example.com